# groupby.mean() doesn't show another column

Tags: pandas

```
"""
csv have three column, some_column, int_type_column, object_type_column
"""
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv')

groups = df.groupby('some_column')

# convert object_type_column to int type
df.loc[df['object_type_column'] == 'value1', 'float_type_column'] = 0
df.loc[df['object_type_column'] == 'value2', 'float_type_column'] = 1

print(groups.mean())

# Output in pandas 1.0.5

some_column  int_type_column
A                 30
B                 20
C                 30
D                 30

# Output in pandas 0.23.4

some_column    int_type_column float_type_column
A                  30                0.2
B                  20                0.4
C                  30                0.8
D                  30                0.1
```

If use pandas 0.23.4 version, float_type_column was converted are output. However, when using pandas version 1.0.5, only int_type_column is output. what's wrong with this?

Comment: What is `occupation_group`? Also `int_type_column` seems like a bad name for a float column... ;)

Comment: @Scotty1- Sorry, I have changed.